# Rails Always Rolls Back with Postgres on Max

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After installing PG and properly setting it up, then running migrations (rake db:create db:migrate db:fixtures:load), Rails never actually saves any records - it simply rolls back everything.

The crazy part is, it doesn't break validations! It assumes automatically that everything has worked, even though Postgres has not actually executed anything.

Here is my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql 
  database: rails_db 
  user: rails
  host: localhost
```

Here is the validation:

```
validates :name, :monthly_budget, :presence => true
```

When I execute a change, it simply does a BEGIN then ROLLBACK. No changes work, but everything validates.

Comment: Disabling all validations changes nothing. Adding them to the question now.

Comment: The crazy thing is this works fine in SQLite too.

Comment: Fixtures loaded properly and so did a raw INSERT or UPDATE

Comment: Got some actual code that shows things validating but being rolled back on save anyway?